# String implementation and can't seem to use the arrow operator

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am supposed to write a Modul for string implementation and I have a rough idea how and where to start. But I keep getting an error every time I try to use the arrow operator in C.

SET - is supposed to allocate the memory and initialise the string with the input.
COPY - copy copies one string to another
CONCAT - concatenation
PRINT - prints it out in the end

So any help would be appreciated:

Header File:

```
    #ifndef string_h
    #define string_h

    typedef struct {
     int len;
     char *s;
    } string_t;

    typedef string_t *string;

    void set(string *s1, char *s);
    void copy(string *s1, string s2);
    void concat(string *s1, string s2);
    void print(string s1);


    #endif /* string_h */
```

Implementation File:

```
    #include "string.h"
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>


    void set(string *s1, char *s) {
      s1 = (string*) malloc (sizeof(string));
 
      if(s == NULL) {
        s1 -> len = 0;
      } else {
        s1 -> len = strlen(s);
        s1 = (string*) malloc (sizeof(s1 -> len));
        s1 -> s = s;
      }

    }

    void copy (string *s1, string s2) {

    }

    void concat(string *s1, string s2) {

    }

    void print(string s1) {

    }
```

Header files seems perfectly fine, as there's not much it does. But the Compiler gives out an error for "s1 -> len" every time. So if anyone could help me out here, I'd be grateful, Thanks.

Comment: Since `set()`'s `s1` argument is effectively a pointer to a pointer to `string_t` (which is what you need, so that's good), you need to dereference it in your `malloc()` line.  You need to set *what it points to* to the address of the memory you allocate, and allocate space for a `string_t` rather than a `string`: `*s1 = malloc(sizeof(string_t));`

Comment: I just did, but It still didn't solve that "s1 -> len" error

Comment: Dereference there too: `(*s1)->len`

Comment: Or use a local `string tmp` instead of `s1` within the function, then set `*s1 = tmp` before returning.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked! and one more question. Do I have to dereference it in the if statement as well? I mean it'd be something like this: **(*s1) = malloc (sizeof((*s1) -> len));**

Comment: Everywhere you use it as a pointer to the `string_t` struct, you'll need to dereference it... since it's effectively a `string_t **` and not a `string_t *`

Answer (score 2):

`s1` seems to be a pointer to pointer, not a pointer to structure type.

You can just change the `typedef` to remove the pointer type, or just use `string` type (not `string *`), as it itself is a pointer already otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought but I have no idea how to fix/use that in my implementation without changing the header file..

Comment: @dean_winchester Just given the hint  in the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I just saw that! But I don't know if I am even allowed to change the parameters and the header file because that's what the professor gave us. So I was wondering if there was any other way to solve it without changing the header file.

Comment: @dean_winchester: Just use `string` in the implementation, NOT `string*`. No need to change the header file at all.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Yes, but since the procedure is declared in the headerfile so I'd  have to change it's parameters there as well.

Comment: @dean_winchester: No, you will just have to use the appropriate indirection to make it fit the sig in the header. That's why everyone except academically cloistered professors knows that "typedef"-ing pointer types is a VERY bad idea.

Comment: He's allocating the structure inside the `set()` function, so he does need the double pointer.  He just needs to change the function body to use it properly.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: Thank You, I know what you mean but I am not sure if I am even allowed to change the procedures and their parameters. or that typedef statement. I even wrote an email to my professor, but he still hasn't responded so I am stuck