# why variable s1 in the set function is a pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure

i am newbie of C/C++ and going to review today and find out this topic

[String implementation and can't seem to use the arrow operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65344929/string-implementation-and-cant-seem-to-use-the-arrow-operator/65378372#65378372)

I am interested in why variable s1 in set() function is a pointer to pointer.
and I google it . C tutorial ,w3school, examples of malloc() exmaples of structure and pointers..etc

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm
the example in the above website is doing the "same" thing but the variable is a pointer but not pointer to pointer

could anyone tell me in detail  why s1 is a pointer to pointer but not a pointer... please .? thank you !

Comment: In what way is `malloc` doing "the same thing"? It does not take any pointer variables as paramter at all. Have you looked closer to the types in volved in the `set` function from the linked example? What is the typ of data where the pointer points to?

Comment: i am not offensive.  but i have a question about the header file in the example
  #ifndef string_h
    #define string_h

    typedef struct {
     int len;
     char *s;
    } string_t;

    typedef string_t *string;

does it typedef  string_t  to the pointer of string..?

Comment: Yes, `string` is already a pointer. `string *` is the same as `string_t **` which is a pointer to pointer. If you want only the structure, you need `string_t`. This kind of confusion it why it is considered bad practice to hide such a pointer type in a typedef.

Comment: i got the point ! thx a lot